# Is it safe to use mysql_affected_rows

Tags: php, mysql

Is it ok to use mysql_affected_rows to get the number of rows affected while doing an update by a user? What if there are several users updating their passwords and I need to know if each users update was successful or not. So if 3 users did updates simultaneously, mysql_affected_rows might return 2 even if one users update was not successful. Is that how it is? I cannot test with multiple users simultaneously. How safe is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe. It only returns data about the last query in your own connection.

[PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) (thanks to [Fluffeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1450077/fluffeh)):

> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with ***link_identifier***.

Since it's a thin wrapper over MySQL C API, we can also [check that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-affected-rows.html):

> my_ulonglong mysql_affected_rows(MYSQL *mysql)

It's not explicitly said anywhere as far as I can see, but it does take the connection identifier and [it seems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/getting-unique-id.html) that the general pattern is that all the functions return data about the specific connection:

> Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement *that* client executed.

Anyways, it would be pretty unusable if you could not be sure whether the result you obtained is yours or not.

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) *Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.* +1

Answer (score 2):

It's safe and returns value for your current DB connection ([mysql-affected-rows function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)).

Answer (score 0):

It's safe because it's connection-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the reference to your connection as a parameter, it is specific to that connection, and therefore safe to use, even if there are simultaneous users accessing your script - because they will each use a separate connection! See the [documentation for mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

Note however, that the mysql extension as a whole is deprecated. Consider switching to  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead!

Answer (score 0):

I use `mysql_query("SELECT ROW_COUNT();");`. I always found it worked better.

Comment: better how? what benefit does it have?